# Having just one selected item in javascript by add & remove classlist

Tags: javascript

I have prepared code below but i have some UI problems with it i want it to have one selected item at first and display the service content belongs to it then change the content & selected box by user click it is working fine with changing the content but it will not remove the orange border from the old box.
it will be great if someone can help me with it.

```js
function changeContent(service) {
    document.getElementById(service).classList.remove("selected-service");
    switch(service) {
        default:
        document.getElementById("services-content").innerHTML = service
        document.getElementById(service).classList.add("selected-service");
    } 
}
```

```css
.our-services div {
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
border-radius: 20px;
        padding: 30px;
    display: flex;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
}
.our-services div h4 {
    margin-bottom:0!important
}

.selected-service {
        border: 2px dashed #ff7200;
}

.our-services {
    direction: ltr;
    text-align: center;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
grid-column-gap: 25px;
grid-row-gap: 25px;
}

.data-center { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2; }
.VDSL { grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3; }
.ADSL2+ { grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4; }
.TD-LTE { grid-area: 1 / 4 / 2 / 5; }
.dedicatd-bandwidth { grid-area: 1 / 5 / 2 / 6; }
.VOIP { grid-area: 2 / 5 / 3 / 6; }
.SIP-TRUNK { grid-area: 3 / 5 / 4 / 6; }
.content { grid-area: 2 / 1 / 4 / 5; }
```

```html
    <div class="our-services">
  <div onclick="changeContent('adsl')" id="adsl" class="ADSL2+"> 
      <img src="http://31.184.128.92/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/adsl-1-1-1.png" alt="ADSL2+"/>
    
      <h4>
        ADSL2+
      </h4>
  </div>

  <div onclick="changeContent('vdsl')" id="vdsl" class="VDSL">
     <img src="http://31.184.128.92/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Group-21874-1.png" alt="VDSL"/>
    
    <h4>
      VDSL
    </h4>
  </div>

  <div onclick="changeContent('voip')" id="voip" class="VOIP">
      <img src="http://31.184.128.92/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/voip-1-1.png" alt="VOIP"/>
    
      <h4>
        تلفن ثابت 
      </h4>
   </div>

  <div onclick="changeContent('tdlte')" id="tdlte" class="TD-LTE">
        <img src="http://31.184.128.92/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Group-21-1.png" alt="TD-LTE"/>
    
      <h4>
        TD-LTE
      </h4>
  </div>

  <div onclick="changeContent('bandwidth')" id="bandwidth" class="dedicatd-bandwidth  selected-service">
      <img src="http://31.184.128.92/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Group-22.png" alt="dedicatd-bandwidth"/>
    
      <h4>
      bandwidth
      </h4>
  </div>

  <div onclick="changeContent('datacenter')" id="datacenter" class="data-center">
    <img src="http://31.184.128.92/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/data-center-2-1.png" alt="datacenter"/>
    
    <h4>
      دیتاسنتر
    </h4>
  </div>
   
   
  <div onclick="changeContent('siptrunk')" id="siptrunk" class="SIP-TRUNK">
     <img src="http://31.184.128.92/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/voip-3-1.png" alt="SIP-TRUNK"/>
    
      <h4>
        SIP  /  
      </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="services-content" class="content">
    <p class="services-title m-0">
      پهنای باند اختصاصی 
    </p>
    
    <p class="services-sub-description">
     description
    </p>
    
    <p class="services-description m-0">
    hhhhhhhh
    </p>

  <span style="display:flex;justify-content-center;align-items:center;margin-top:65px">
    <button style="border:1px solid #FF7200;color:#FF7200;padding:14px 32px;background:#fff;border-radius:50px">
        مشاهده و خرید
    </button>
  </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to unselect all of the other elements besides the one that has just been selected?

Comment: So that there's only 1 selected element

Comment: @Aifos Si Prahs exactly

Comment: I have added an updated answer, with cleaner code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clicking,you need to remove class `selected-service` for all elements and assign it to the current element

```
let eles = document.querySelectorAll('.selected-service')
for(let i=0;i<eles.length;i++){
  eles[i].classList.remove('selected-service'); 
}
```

Or we can use a variable to store the previous cliked element and the next time just remove style from the previous one

Note:  `document.getElementById(service).classList.remove("selected-service");` will just remove class from the current element.

```js
function changeContent(service) {
    let eles = document.querySelectorAll('.selected-service')
    for(let i=0;i<eles.length;i++){
      eles[i].classList.remove('selected-service'); 
    }
    switch(service) {
        default:
        document.getElementById("services-content").innerHTML = service
        document.getElementById(service).classList.add("selected-service");
    } 
}
```

```css
.our-services div {
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
border-radius: 20px;
        padding: 30px;
    display: flex;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
}
.our-services div h4 {
    margin-bottom:0!important
}

.selected-service {
        border: 2px dashed #ff7200;
}

.our-services {
    direction: ltr;
    text-align: center;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
grid-column-gap: 25px;
grid-row-gap: 25px;
}

.data-center { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2; }
.VDSL { grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3; }
.ADSL2+ { grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4; }
.TD-LTE { grid-area: 1 / 4 / 2 / 5; }
.dedicatd-bandwidth { grid-area: 1 / 5 / 2 / 6; }
.VOIP { grid-area: 2 / 5 / 3 / 6; }
.SIP-TRUNK { grid-area: 3 / 5 / 4 / 6; }
.content { grid-area: 2 / 1 / 4 / 5; }
```

```html
<div class="our-services">
  <div onclick="changeContent('adsl')" id="adsl" class="ADSL2+"> 
      <img src="http://31.184.128.92/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/adsl-1-1-1.png" alt="ADSL2+"/>
    
      <h4>
        ADSL2+
      </h4>
  </div>

  <div onclick="changeContent('vdsl')" id="vdsl" class="VDSL">
     <img src="http://31.184.128.92/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Group-21874-1.png" alt="VDSL"/>
    
    <h4>
      VDSL
    </h4>
  </div>

  <div onclick="changeContent('voip')" id="voip" class="VOIP">
      <img src="http://31.184.128.92/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/voip-1-1.png" alt="VOIP"/>
    
      <h4>
        تلفن ثابت 
      </h4>
   </div>

  <div onclick="changeContent('tdlte')" id="tdlte" class="TD-LTE">
        <img src="http://31.184.128.92/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Group-21-1.png" alt="TD-LTE"/>
    
      <h4>
        TD-LTE
      </h4>
  </div>

  <div onclick="changeContent('bandwidth')" id="bandwidth" class="dedicatd-bandwidth  selected-service">
      <img src="http://31.184.128.92/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Group-22.png" alt="dedicatd-bandwidth"/>
    
      <h4>
      bandwidth
      </h4>
  </div>

  <div onclick="changeContent('datacenter')" id="datacenter" class="data-center">
    <img src="http://31.184.128.92/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/data-center-2-1.png" alt="datacenter"/>
    
    <h4>
      دیتاسنتر
    </h4>
  </div>
   
   
  <div onclick="changeContent('siptrunk')" id="siptrunk" class="SIP-TRUNK">
     <img src="http://31.184.128.92/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/voip-3-1.png" alt="SIP-TRUNK"/>
    
      <h4>
        SIP  /  
      </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="services-content" class="content">
    <p class="services-title m-0">
      پهنای باند اختصاصی 
    </p>
    
    <p class="services-sub-description">
     description
    </p>
    
    <p class="services-description m-0">
    hhhhhhhh
    </p>

  <span style="display:flex;justify-content-center;align-items:center;margin-top:65px">
    <button style="border:1px solid #FF7200;color:#FF7200;padding:14px 32px;background:#fff;border-radius:50px">
        مشاهده و خرید
    </button>
  </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const elements = ['adsl', 'vdsl', 'voip', 'tdlte', 'bandwidth', 'datacenter', 'siptrunk' ];

elements.forEach((el, i) => document.querySelector(`#${el}`).onclick = () => changeContent(el));
function changeContent(service) {
    document.querySelector('.selected-service').classList.remove("selected-service");
        document.getElementById("services-content").innerHTML = service
        document.getElementById(service).classList.add("selected-service");
    
}
```

```css
/*add this line below so that the elements don't look "jumping" when they get selected*/
.our-services div[id] {
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.our-services div {
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
border-radius: 20px;
        padding: 30px;
    display: flex;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
}
.our-services div h4 {
    margin-bottom:0!important
}

.selected-service {
        border: 2px dashed #ff7200!important;
}

.our-services {
    direction: ltr;
    text-align: center;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
grid-column-gap: 25px;
grid-row-gap: 25px;
}

.data-center { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2; }
.VDSL { grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3; }
.ADSL2+ { grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4; }
.TD-LTE { grid-area: 1 / 4 / 2 / 5; }
.dedicatd-bandwidth { grid-area: 1 / 5 / 2 / 6; }
.VOIP { grid-area: 2 / 5 / 3 / 6; }
.SIP-TRUNK { grid-area: 3 / 5 / 4 / 6; }
.content { grid-area: 2 / 1 / 4 / 5; }
```

```html
<div class="our-services">
  <div id="adsl" class="ADSL2+"> 
      <img src="http://31.184.128.92/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/adsl-1-1-1.png" alt="ADSL2+"/>
    
      <h4>
        ADSL2+
      </h4>
  </div>

  <div id="vdsl" class="VDSL">
     <img src="http://31.184.128.92/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Group-21874-1.png" alt="VDSL"/>
    
    <h4>
      VDSL
    </h4>
  </div>

  <div id="voip" class="VOIP">
      <img src="http://31.184.128.92/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/voip-1-1.png" alt="VOIP"/>
    
      <h4>
        تلفن ثابت 
      </h4>
   </div>

  <div id="tdlte" class="TD-LTE">
        <img src="http://31.184.128.92/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Group-21-1.png" alt="TD-LTE"/>
    
      <h4>
        TD-LTE
      </h4>
  </div>

  <div id="bandwidth" class="dedicatd-bandwidth  selected-service">
      <img src="http://31.184.128.92/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Group-22.png" alt="dedicatd-bandwidth"/>
    
      <h4>
      bandwidth
      </h4>
  </div>

  <div id="datacenter" class="data-center">
    <img src="http://31.184.128.92/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/data-center-2-1.png" alt="datacenter"/>
    
    <h4>
      دیتاسنتر
    </h4>
  </div>
   
   
  <div class="selected-element" id="siptrunk" class="SIP-TRUNK">
     <img src="http://31.184.128.92/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/voip-3-1.png" alt="SIP-TRUNK"/>
    
      <h4>
        SIP  /  
      </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="services-content" class="content">
    <p class="services-title m-0">
      پهنای باند اختصاصی 
    </p>
    
    <p class="services-sub-description">
     description
    </p>
    
    <p class="services-description m-0">
    hhhhhhhh
    </p>

  <span style="display:flex;justify-content-center;align-items:center;margin-top:65px">
    <button style="border:1px solid #FF7200;color:#FF7200;padding:14px 32px;background:#fff;border-radius:50px">
        مشاهده و خرید
    </button>
  </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, your images are not showing up as http://31.184.128.92 is a local address and is not available to anyone besides your computer until you deploy your Wordpress website on hosting